# React: Why won't this <select> render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just started using React and I'm already stuck.

I've already gotten other elements to work just fine but for whatever reason select elements refuse to render. What am I doing wrong?

Select.jsx:

```
var React = require('react');

var Select = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <select>
                <option>Hi there</option>
            </select>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Select;
```

main.jsx

```
var Select = require('./Select');

ReactDOM.render(<Select />, document.getElementById('Select-filter-by'));
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Select-filter-by"></div>
```

Again, I've got other things working just fine (checkboxes and a select all button for them).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you have any errors?

Comment: should work https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/50830/

Comment: Are you calling `ReactDOM.render` multiple times?

Comment: no errors... something has got to be wrong with my IDE, server... something. this makes no sense

Comment: @azium yes i am...

Comment: @BradEvans then that's the issue.....

Comment: Maybe you're overwriting the element? It's very atypical to call ReactDOM.render more than once.

Comment: But I've been calling ReactDOM.render multiple times for days now...

Comment: I can see how I wouldn't want to call it more than once but as I was learning I just kept adding more. The bad news is that removing the others gives the same result.

Comment: Appears to work fine.. https://jsfiddle.net/uqmvh6zs/1/

Comment: What if you embed the `Select` component inside one of the render calls that does work?

Comment: No luck. This is infuriating at this point.

Comment: It feels like it's something else in your setup that's the problem here, perhaps your build step or etc. Perhaps clone one of the react boilerplates and try again, (or maybe even better try the new tooling mentioned https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html)

Comment: add a `console.log` in your select's render method to see if the select actually loads or not. If you see the console.log then something is overwriting it.

Comment: I've done that. I've also placed it elsewhere in html - and it works. I've stepped away from it for now to retain some sanity. Tomorrow I'll run it by some team members - I think there has got to be something outside the front end going on that is affecting this.

Comment: Is the project in a public repo that can be ran?